# Where can I get a summary of the changes between zmq 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: zeromq

Looking around the web doesn't really net my any useful resources. Is there a definitive change log posted anywhere?

The best I could find was: http://www.zeromq.org/docs:3-0

But the comment at the top doesn't look very encouraging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you need you can probably find the answers here:

- [Upgading from ZeroMq 2.x to 3.2](http://www.zeromq.org/docs:3-1-upgrade)
- [ZeroMq release notes (3.0 -> 3.2.2 Stable)](https://raw.github.com/zeromq/zeromq3-x/master/NEWS). (I think this includes all changes from 2.2 Stable to 3.2.2 Stable)

One think to note regarding 3.1 Beta and forward; "The key change is a new wire protocol with full backwards compatibility with 0MQ/2.2.", found [here](http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2012-October/018914.html) (also mentioned in the release notes above).